# Conjugate Gradient: A-orthogonality under quadratic form implies "regular" orthogonality under special mapping...

Tags: optimization, transformation, quadratic-forms, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have been reading through an article on the method of conjugate gradients (in solving a system $\textbf{A}x=b$). You can find the article [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf).

In the article, we consider the quadratic form $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}x^\top\textbf{A}x - b^\top x + c$ where $\textbf{A}$ is symmetric, positive-definite. Of course, in the 2D case, the contour lines of $f(x)$ are ellipses. On a graph of these ellipses, it is stated toward the bottom of p. 22 that $\textbf{A}$-orthogonality of two vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $u^\top \textbf{A} v = 0$ implies regular orthogonality ($u^\top v = 0$) when the graph is stretched such that the elliptical contours of $f(x)$ are transformed into circles.

I would love to try and prove this, but I'm not really sure where to start. I feel like a good place to begin would be to analyze the quadratic form to figure out what transformation matrix is necessary to convert its contours into circles.

Comment: in the case when $A$ is symmetric positive definite, there are many ways to find a matrix $C$ such that $C^T C = A,$ where it is then automatic that $C$ is invertible. Introduce a different vector $z = Cx$  and $x = C^{-1}z,$  the new figure is $\frac{1}{2}  z^T z - ( b^T C^{-1} z + c.$ The contour surfaces are now spheres

Comment: Oh wow, that is great thinking. Thank you Will. So since we have defined a transformation $x' = Cx$ where $C^\top C = A$, $u^\top A v = 0 \implies u^\top \left(C^\top C\right)v = \left(u^\top C^\top\right) \left(Cv\right) = u'^\top v' =0.$ Thus, $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal under the coordinate transform $C$ that makes the quadratic form surface contours spherical.

Comment: Oh! And your assumption that $A$ is symmetric, positive-definite was also made by the method I'm considering. I'll add that to the original post.